# How hide label in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a dynamic page and using CoffeScript

```
class Requistion < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class RequistionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @requistion = Requistion.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @requistion = Requistion.new(user_params)
    @requistion.save
  end

  def index
    @requistions = Requistion.all
  end


  def new
    @requistion = Requistion.new
  end

  private
  def user_params
        params.require(:requistion).permit(:object)
  end
end
```

View code:

```
<%= f.label :info, :'text',  class: "col-md-4 control-label" %>
<%= f.text_field :info,  class: "form-control" %>
```

Below is the JQuery code.

`$('#class_info').parent().hide()`

The field is hidden, although label is not. What's the problem?

Comment: Please show the code where the id `class_info` is actually defined.  All i see is that you want to use it, but where do you actually define it in the HTML.

Comment: Could you be more specific with the code.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know how well the insert code

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View code:

```
<%= f.label :info, :'text',  class: "col-md-4 control-label hidden" %>
<%= f.text_field :info,  class: "form-control hidden" %>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```